# C#ダイアログのViewModel内で自身のダイアログをクローズしたい

Tags: c#

C#(Visual studio2015)で メイン画面からダイアログを表示しています。

◆メインのViewModel

```
    Object _dialogContent;
    public Object DialogContent
    {
        get { return _dialogContent; }
        set
        {
            _dialogContent = value;
            this.SetProperty(ref this._dialogContent, value);
        }
    }

    private async void MyDialogShowAsync()
    {
        Exception excep = null;
        try
        {
            var vm = new MyDialogViewModel();
            DialogContent = new MyDialog { DataContext = vm };
            await DialogHost.Show(DialogContent, "RootDialog");
            excep = vm.Excep;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

◆ダイアログのView
            
                    Command="{x:Static DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}"/>
            
                    Command="{x:Static DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}"/>

ダイアログのボタンを押すとダイアログがクローズされます。

ボタンを押下した場合に、何かしらの処理を実施後にクローズしたいと考え、

◆ダイアログのViewModel

```
    public DelegateCommand ClancelComamnd { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand OKComamnd { get; set; }

    コンストラクタに以下を用意しました。
        this.ClancelComamnd = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
        ★①
        });
        this.OKComamnd = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
        ★②
        });
```

◆ダイアログのViewも以下のように修正しました。
            
                    Command="{Binding OKComamnd}"/>
            
                    Command="{Binding ClancelComamnd}"/>

ダイアログのキャンセルボタン、OKボタンを押下すると★①、★②が通ることは確認できたのですが、
その後、自身のダイアログをどのようにクローズしていいのかがわかりません。
★①、★②で何かしらを実施するとクローズは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DialogHost`は`MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit`のものでしょうか？でしたら[ドキュメント](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs#close-dialog-strategies)には三種類の方法が記載されています。

1. `Show`メソッドの引数で`DialogOpened`イベントを購読し、イベント引数のメソッドを使用する。

例えば

```
class MyDialogViewModel
{
    internal DialogSession Session { get; set;}
    void Close() => Session?.Close();
}

await DialogHost.Show(DialogContent, "RootDialog", (s, e) => vm.Session = e.Session);
```

2. 組み込みの`RoutedCommand`を使用する。これはVM内からは難しいです。
3. `DialogHost.IsOpen`プロパティを`False`に変更する。

これは「メインのViewModel」で適当な`bool`プロパティを定義し、`DialogHost.IsOpen`に双方向バインドしたうえで`MyDialogViewModel`に「メインのViewModel」を渡せばこのプロパティに`false`を設定することでダイアログが閉じられるようになります。

どちらか好みの方で実装してください。

Comment: 丁寧なアドバイスありがとうございます！案１にて実施し、閉じることを確認できました。DialogOpenedではなくDialogCloseのほうばかり見ていたので、目からうろこでした。勉強になりました。案3についてはまだ理解に及ばず、双方向バインドについて見直したいと思います。